# Error ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/squareup/picasso/RequestWeakReference

Tags: java, android, gradle, duplicates

I use external lib called Picasso, theme Appcompat, android Recyclerview, CardView

This morning my app compiled and worked well, but then I imported another project that gave me choice: java 1.8 or Android sdk 21; I suspect i chose wrong thing - java1.8 and then my first app stopped building.
I had problem with multidex and put it to true

I already checked similar posts on SO:

- i checked for duplicate libs in External libs folder
- i put multidexEnabled true
- i avoided + signs in dependencies libs version and replaced with numbers

this is my gradle app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kaban.it_ebooksinfomobile"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'

}
```

Now, i have this **duplicate entry lib RequestWeak reference** error with Picasso library, but i have no duplicate lib!

[image: it-ebooks]

Comment: Hi @ERJAN, I have same problem like you. Can you please share how you solve this issue if it was done.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same issue but I fixed it by removing the Picasso plugin from my build file

```
  'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1'
```

It was because I had another plugin in my gradle file that had another copy of the Picasso dependency. My error disappeared.